# How to use the path with the space in docker file

Tags: dockerfile

I want to write a cmd in docker file to copy the file at the destination `C:\windows\Program Files`. I am having an issue due to space in program files. I am able to copy the file to different location. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

I am getting below error:

Step 4 : COPY "C:\docker\prerequisites\MicrosoftSDKs" "C:\Program Files
(x86)\MicrosoftSDKs"

Forbidden path outside the build context: C:\docker\prerequisites\MicrosoftSDKs
 ()

Comment: 1 - Wrap the path in quotes. 2 - Escape the space, like this `Program\ Files'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ARG:

```
ARG sourc = "C:\docker\prerequisites\MicrosoftSDKs"
ARG destination = "C:\Program Files (x86)\MicrosoftSDKs"
COPY ${sourc} ${destination}
```

Answer (score 30):

Use the JSON form, you have to use double backslashes inside the braces

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore 
COPY ["C:\\docker\\prerequisites\\MicrosoftSDKs", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MicrosoftSDKs"]
```

You can also use slash:

```
COPY ["C:/Program Files/nodejs", "/windows/system32"]
```

Answer (score -1):

workaround:
write the script with the spaces into a file, and in the docker file, run the script by calling the file.

in a file named myscript.bat write
COPY "C:\docker\prerequisites\MicrosoftSDKs" "C:\Program Files (x86)\MicrosoftSDKs"

and in the DockerFile

RUN myscript.bat

Answer (score -4):

Enclosing the path in quotes like this should help if there are spaces:

```
"C:\windows\Program Files"
```