# Dockerfile: COPY / ADD with space character in path (Windows)

Tags: windows, docker, path, dockerfile

In Windows 10 (cmd) I'm trying to copy a file from a subfolder containing a space character in its name.

1. First I tried to use quotation marks:

   ```
   FROM jfloff/alpine-python:2.7
   COPY "Folder 1/File.txt" "Dir 1"
   ```

   Error message:

   > failed to process **"\"Folder"**: unexpected end of statement while looking for matching double-quote
2. "JSON" format (skipped the first line):

   ```
   COPY ["Folder 1/File.txt" "Dir 1"]
   ```

   Error message:

   > failed to process **"[\"Folder"**: unexpected end of statement while looking for matching double-quote
3. Trying to escape with a single backslash:

   ```
   COPY "Folder\ 1/File.txt" "Dir\ 1"
   ```

   Error message:

   > failed to process **"\"Folder\\"**: unexpected end of statement while looking for matching double-quote
4. Trying to escape with a double backslash:

   ```
   COPY "Folder\\ 1/File.txt" "Dir\\ 1"
   ```

   Error message:

   > failed to process **"\"Folder\\\\"**: unexpected end of statement while looking for matching double-quote
5. Also tried a suggestion to use **%20** instead of space:

   ```
   COPY ["Folder%201/File.txt" "Dir%201"]
   ```

   Error message:

   > COPY failed: no source File
6. Escape character replacement:

   ```
   # escape=`
   COPY "Folder` 1/File.txt" "Dir 1"
   ```

   Error message:

   > failed to process **"\"Folder`"**: unexpected end of statement while looking for matching double-quote
7. The same, but without quotes:

   ```
   #escape=`
   COPY Folder` 1/File.txt Dir` 1
   ```

   Error message:

   > COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder082039614/**Folder**: no such file or directory
8. Method with packing / unpacking using a **tar** archive (I'm not happy with that idea).

It should be possible, shouldn't it?

Comment: Can this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43551830/9797889) help you? Use absolute path?

Comment: @menya Unfortunately, it didn't help

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Maybe you can use `ARG` to help you, like this:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM jfloff/alpine-python:2.7
ARG src="Folder 1/File.txt"
ARG target="Dir 1/"
COPY ${src} ${target}
```

BTW, a `/` has to be add at the end of `Dir 1` if you treat really want to treat it as a folder.

And, JSON format is also ok, just you miss `,`, it should be:

```
FROM jfloff/alpine-python:2.7
COPY ["Folder 1/File.txt", "Dir 1/"]
```

**Update for your comments:**

In [official guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy), it said:

> When copying files or directories that contain special characters (such as [ and ]), you need to escape those paths following the Golang rules to prevent them from being treated as a matching pattern.

So, for your case, it should be:

```
FROM jfloff/alpine-python:2.7
ARG src="[[]Folder 1]/__SLIM_TEMPLATE.mm"
ARG target="[Folder 1]/"
COPY ${src} ${target}
```

Or:

```
FROM jfloff/alpine-python:2.7
COPY ["[[]Folder 1]/__SLIM_TEMPLATE.mm", "[Folder 1]/"]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seem that I've got problem with path that not only contains whitespaces, but also square brackets and underscores: ARG src="[_Folder 1_]/__SLIM_TEMPLATE.mm"
ARG target="[_Folder 1_]/"
COPY ${src} ${target}  , it fails with a message: COPY failed: no source files were specified. I tried escaping the brackets, with no success

Answer (score 7):

The solution is the follow:
[image]

Docker has updated it's `COPY` command. So you can use brackets and your filenames can have whitespaces. Read more here ([official docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy))

Answer (score 2):

agree it's annoying to get files from docker that have special characters,
had similar experience and after hours of try and errors, I came up with this simple solution that I now use since then.

tar/zip the files and then "docker cp" them easily without having to worry about dozens of []'"..

tar files in your container machine:

```
#zipped
tar czf myfiles.tar.gz file1.txt dir24 file_xyz

#or unzipped
tar -cvf myfiles.tar file1.txt dir24 file_xyz
```

Then copy them to local directories in your windows machine.

open cmd in windows
run

```
# docker cp ABCD_CONTAINER_NAME:PATH/myfiles.tar.gz d:/TARGETDIR/
```

check if files have been transferred in d:/TARGETDIR/