# Docker CP can't copy file names that have "\" in them

Tags: windows, docker

Has anyone been able to use Docker cp on windows to copy files from container with names like "C:\ABC\Logs\ABC- PPZ API20210325.log"?

This is the command I run on Windows host:
`docker cp` objective_archimedes:"/app/C:\ABC\Logs\ABC- PPZ API20210325.log"

Error: No such container:path: objective_archimedes:/app/C:\ABC\Logs\ABC- PPZ API20210325.log

The container is running an asp.net core image `aspnet:3.1-buster-slim`

Comment: I don't know Docker Windows, but have you tried adding an `backslash` before each `backslash`? For example `C:\\ABC\\Logs\\ABC- PPZ API20210325.log`

Comment: I have and it didn't work.

Comment: I've found https://stackoverflow.com/a/56420474/5790653. Does it help you?